# ImportError: No module named 'ase.build'

Tags: python, python-3.x

In ubuntu 16.04 i installed python and modules:

```
sudo apt install python3 python3-scipy python3-numpy python3-ase
```

then i try to follow [the first tutorial](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/tutorials/surface.html) on the [ASE homepage](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html). I run `python3` in `bash` terminal, and can import other modules but not `ase-build`. It looks like this:

```
>>> from ase.optimize import QuasiNewton
>>> from ase.build import fcc111, add_adsorbate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'ase.build'
>>>
```

Using a python script throws an equivalent error. 
What could be the problem?

**UPDATE & SOLUTION** 
Seems this was not really even a python problem. I seem to have had some package dependency errors probably due to not running `apt update` in a long time between program installations. I removed `python2.x` and `python 3.x`, then iterated `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt autoremove`, then reinstalled only `python3`. I installed `python3-pip` and installed the numpy, scipy, and ase packages using the proper form `python3 -m pip install --upgrade <package>`. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: did you try another `python3` interpreter? type `python3` and press TAB to check what other versions you have installed

Comment: @mic4ael I did as you say. I have 3.5, 3.5m and 3m, but they throw the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what version of the library you have.

```
import ase
print(ase.__version__)
```

If the version is `3.10.0` then that is the problem since the `build` module appeared (as far as I know) in the `3.11.0` version.

Comment: sorry I forgot you are using python 3 (check my updated answer)

Comment: I'm being told `AttributeError: module 'ase' has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: can you run `import ase;dir(ase)`?

Comment: Yes, I get: `['Atom', 'Atoms', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'atom', 'atoms', 'data', 'units', 'utils']`

Comment: try to install `ase` module via `pip` since the one provided by the system might be obsolete

Answer (score 0):

Due to [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-ase) - you have installed the 3.9.1.4567-3 version on your computer.

But The **asu.build** has been added in:

> commit 71c9563e423e2add645c26f8d0a722f3db13e135
>
> Author: Jens Jørgen Mortensen
>
> Date:   Tue Apr 12 15:40:59 2016 +0200
>
> Move stuff to ase.build module

So, the module **asu.build** doesn't exist in your version (3.9 has been released in 2015). You have to install the newer version of python3-asu.

Comment: Just try to download python3-asu from this version: http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/python3-ase